# What's the difference between EMSE vs. IMSE when buying components? (Linear Technology parts?)

Tags: switching-regulator, buying

For example, see [this page](http://www.linear.com/purchase/LTC3388) for buying a LTC3388 step-down regulator, and note the difference between the LTC3388**EMSE**-1#PBF and LTC3388**IMSE**-1#PBF.

What's the difference? Is this notation specific just to components from Linear Technology? Why is one more expensive than the other?

I've tried to Google this a number of times with no luck.

Edit: I've also seen EDD vs. IDD. What does the 'E' and 'I' stand for in all of these acronyms?

(It'd be helpful to know what the rest of the letters stand for too)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [the datasheet](http://www.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/338813f.pdf) (page 4, note 2):

> The LTC3388E-1/LTC3388E-3 are guaranteed to meet
>   specifications from 0°C to 85°C junction temperature. Specifications over
>   the –40°C to 125°C operating junction temperature range are assured by
>   design, characterization and correlation with statistical process controls.
>   The LTC3388I-1/LTC3388I-3 are guaranteed over the –40°C to 125°C
>   operating junction temperature range.

In short, both can be used over the full -40°C to 125°C range, but only the parts with an `I` have the specifications guaranteed over the full range (possibly meaning binning).